# VB.net Load a dll at runtime from another folder. And Still Be freindly with VIsual Studios

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, dll, marshalling

So I'm at a bit of a loss on how I can set this up. I have a program that i "marshal" into memory ("As a anti de-compiling measure") and run it. Thar works fine. However I now wish to include some code that id like to share, and some that id like not to share.

For instance i have a Settings class that that has a few static variables that gets populated from a init() method that takes a argument of SettingClass that handles reading and writing to the file.

```
Public Class Settings
    Public Shared somesetting As String

    Public Shared Sub Init(ByRef sett As SettingFile)
       somesetting = sett.ReadValue("group", "somthing")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Its a little weird yes, but it makes the code easyer to read from the main program as

```
Setting.somesetting
```

That is just an example as there may be a few dozen variables. This too also works fine, up until i started cleaning up the code, as i took this class and a few others and compiled them into a dll. Aslong as the dll is in the same folder, it works fime. Therein lies the problem, when this is deployed i will not be able to have the dll in the folder with the program.

What i have tried is setting up the settings file to be a list and then just pass along the information as command line arguments and calling somthing like

```
Setting.getVal("Something")
```

That too also worked, but the other person working on the project found it difficult to remember so it had to be removed.

The next thing i have tried is embedding the dll, but that just dosn't seem to work. As soon as i remove the dll from the folder, complains it cant find it even tho it would have been linked in as a resource.

My current idea is to use some form of "Marshaling"(Think thats the right term) to load the dlls into memory during initialization by downloaindg them as bytestreams and poping them directly into memory.

For instance: in the main.

```
Sub main()
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf ResolveAssemblies
    Console.Writeline(Settings.something) 'No import of setting classes was made uptop.
End Sub

Function ResolveAssemblies(sender As Object, args As System.ResolveEventArgs) As System.Reflection.Assembly
    Dim domain As AppDomain = DirectCast(sender, AppDomain)

    Dim rawAssembly As Byte() = dlByteArrayFromWebserver("Common.dll")
    Dim rawSymbolStore As Byte() = ldlByteArrayFromWebserver("Common.pdb")
    Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = domain.Load(rawAssembly, rawSymbolStore)

    Return myAssembly
End Function
```

This would solve my problem, but i cant seem to get it to play nice with Visual Studios, I make the references in the application properties and i can access the data members, however sense i don't copy the dll into the folder with it, it complains it cant find it, even before i can try to load it into memory.

And the reason for such... Extreme methods is because i know the end users will be malicious. they will try to decompile the code in almost any way they can. Its not a matter of making it impossible to figure out, but just difficult. Not only that but my partner who is also working on this with me only knows vb.net so thats the reason for that.

So my Question is, any idea why this isent working? From my understanding the handler should proc as soon as the program tries to load the missing dependency thus retrieving it. As well as ideas for different setups if this is too... terrible of a design.

Info:

```
launcher.exe <- free to give out, and uses the settings.dll in the same folder

privateprogram.exe <- never want it to touch the hdd. knows the location of settings.dll and needs to load it in to run. it also needs private.dll which it gets the bytesteam from the server
```

Yea i know, its a weird setup. but this is how it needs to be.

Comment: Dude, this is absolutely horrible and is likely to cause you a whole shed-load of unforeseen problems, I would suggest you look into obfuscation instead.

Comment: Yea but deobfuscation is pretty easy(Unless i want to pay hundreds of dollars) and and I wanted it more secure, I can load the exe up fine and it runs if i dont include a dll, the things is that is tedius to handcopy the classes over so i just wanted to know why my loading of a dll from another locationw as being a jerk

Answer (score 0):

You're doomed to failure, but...

Marshalling is not what you need. (Marshalling is to do with going between the Managed - .NET - world and the unmanaged world.) What you need is Reflection - System.Reflection namespace - check out AppDomain; you can either create a new AppDomain in your process and load a dll into it, or load a dll into the current AppDomain, which it looks like you're doing.

However, users will still be able to see your code:

- They can point a Decompiler at your dll and see it straight away (see
  JustDecompile or ILSpy for two free ones)
- They can attach a debugger at run-time to your code and look at the code and the data it's processing.

To make it difficult, as @The Blue Dog suggests, an Obfuscator will make all sorts of name changes in the compiled code. Users will still be able to decompile it but instead of e.g.

```
Public Shared somesetting As String
```

they'll see:

```
Public Shared ql42MXGYHttt5 As String
```

...or something equally unreadable.

But with .NET you can't hide the code you deliver.